# C#: Update embeded resource file at runtime

Tags: c#, resources, embedded-resource

I have a situation, where html files are embedded as resource files in console WebApp and are sent to another app, that hosts them.

I managed to create file change procedure, so that the WebApp is reset and will resend resources, when I edit my html files.

The problem is, embedded files doesn't change.

Is there a way that I can update embedded files at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could save the updated files to a folder, and use those files.

When the applications starts, it first checks if the folder with the new files exist. If they do, the application will use them else the application will fall back on the embedded files.